# Wordpress + PHP: Using array variable with in_array inside another function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am using jcart http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/ to create some cart functionality in wordpress.

I am trying to access a jcart function within another function in my functions.php file.

```
foreach($jcart->get_contents() as $item) {
    $psitems[] = $item['id'];
}
```

This code works fine on functions.php itself or on any template page-- it creates the `$psitems` array so I can check if that array contains certain values.

Now, within the following function:

```
function gallery_shortcode_fancybox($attr) { ...
```

I have the following:

```
foreach($jcart->get_contents() as $item) {
    $psitems[] = $item['id'];
}

foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_image($id, 'full', false, false) : wp_get_attachment_image($id, 'full', true, false);

    $output .= "<div class='property'>";
    $output .= "$link";
    $output .= '
        <div class="property-details">
            <div class="property-details-inner">

                <form method="post" action="" class="jcart">
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="hidden" name="jcartToken" value="' . $_SESSION['jcartToken'] . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-id" value="' . $id . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-name" value="Photo #' . $id . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-url" value="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $id ) . '" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="my-item-qty" value="1" size="3" />';

    if(in_array($id,$psitems)) {
        $output .= '<span class="action terminal pull-sheet">Image in Pullsheet</span>'
    } else {
        $output .=          '<input type="submit" name="my-add-button" value="Add to Pull Sheet" class="action terminal pull-sheet" />';
    }
    $output .=              '</fieldset>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- property-details-inner -->
        </div>';
    $output .= "</div>";
}

return $output;
```

I get the following error:

> Call to a member function get_contents() on a non-object

If I try placing the original `foreach($jcart->get_contents() as $item) { ...` code outside of the function, I get the following error:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in...
```

How can I access this array inside the function and avoid these errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first error, it means that you have to initialize $jcart.

As for the warning, try this:

```
$array = $jcart->get_contents();
foreach ($array as $item) ...
```

Comment: using the initialize function from the original jcart.php script worked perfectly, thanks